# I would like to take a data from in the csv file

Tags: python, csv

this is the equivalent of my csv file;

```
customer,quantity
a,250
a,166
c,354
b,185
a,58
d,68
c,263
c,254
d,320
b,176
d,127
...
```

this csv file has 8000 data. I want to separate the "a", "b", ,"c", ... "z" in the customer column with the quantity column. this csv file is just an example, actually customers are too many. I don't know the customer names. what i want is for each client to have their own csv file. and I have to do them using python.

I'm sorry for my bad english.

Comment: When you say "what i want is for each client to have their own csv file" you'll end up having 8000+ files then? is that what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @votelessbubble he has 8000 rows not customers

Comment: Please provide your wanted csv result for any customer

Comment: @sudden_appearance Ah sorry about that. I misread.

Comment: i need all of them, not special one

Comment: @Furkan777 You can try my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not good in the `pandas` module but I get what you want this code makes the `.csv` of the user name and the inserts his/her name and quantity in the file. You can try this if you get any errors then please let me know in the comment.
**Note: Please try this with a copy of the same data file**

```py
# pip install pandas
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('abc.csv') # write you csv file name here.

all_customer_value = list(data['customer'])
all_customer_quantity = list(data['quantity'])
all_customer_name = set(data['customer'])

for user in all_customer_name:
    with open(f'{user}.csv','w')as file:
        file.write('customer,quantity\n') # edited

for index,value in  enumerate(all_customer_value):
    with open(f'{value}.csv','a') as file:
        file.write(f'{value}, {all_customer_quantity[index]}\n')
```

Comment: it is work to this file, but i am try and convert to the my file, if i am successful come back to answer.

Comment: @Furkan777 I have a question is your main file constant with the same type of data as two-column one name is `customer` and the other name is `quantity`.

Comment: @Furkan777 Welcome, Love from India.

Comment: İkbal no they are not same but convert it and work it

Comment: @Thanks for replying. I hope my code is works for you.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the simplest way is using a `dict` to store the customer name and all related quantities:

```
from csv import reader, writer

with open('the_file.csv', 'r') as file_in:
    csv_in = reader(file_in)
    customers = {}
    first_line = True
    for cust, qty in csv_in:
        if first_line:
            first_line = False
            continue
        if cust not in customers:
            customers[cust] = [qty]
        else:
            customers[cust].append(qty)
    for cust in customers:
        with open(f'{cust}.csv', 'w', newline='') as file_out:
            csv_out = writer(file_out)
            for qty in customers[cust]:
                csv_out.writerow([cust, qty])
```

Comment: your code is also working but you have a problem in your code is you are not adding module names in your post which is not a good practice.

Comment: Correct. Editing my answer to mention the imports

Comment: You could read/skip the first line with a `next(csv_in)` to avoid the `first_line` check. And this might be a good place for a `defaultdict(list)` .

Comment: I've timed all solutions (100 customers, 100_000 rows): A slightly modified version of your solution and my second one are the best, your's seems to have a slight edge though.

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay with Pandas I'd use [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on the dataframe created by [`.read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) (grouping by the customers), and then write the pieces to csv-files with [`.to_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) (replace `file.csv` with your input filename):

```
import pandas as pd

for customer, df in pd.read_csv("file.csv").groupby("customer"):
    df.to_csv(f"{customer}.csv", index=False)
```

---

If you want to do more or less the same without Pandas you could use [`groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) from the standard library's `itertools` module and the `reader` and `writer` from the standard library's [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module:

```
import csv
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby

with open("file.csv", "r") as file:
    data = list(csv.reader(file))
header, data = data[0], data[1:]
key = itemgetter(0)
for customer, group in groupby(sorted(data, key=key), key=key):
    with open(f"{customer}.csv", "w") as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow(header)
        writer.writerows(group)
```

If you want to avoid the sorting, then a solution like the one from @gimix might be better.

---

The most efficient solution I could come up with is the following, in which no file is closed until the end (handled via an [`ExitStack()`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack)) and the input is sorted straight into the correct slot:

```
import csv
from contextlib import ExitStack

writers = {}
with ExitStack() as files:
    reader = csv.reader(files.enter_context(open("file.csv", "r")))
    header = next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        customer = row[0]
        if customer not in writers:
            fout = files.enter_context(open(f"{customer}.csv", "w"))
            writers.setdefault(customer, csv.writer(fout)).writerow(header)
        writers[customer].writerow(row)
```

The trade off here: No intermediary data structuring, but file handle bookkeeping.

(I'd avoid solutions with a potentially excessive amount of file openings/closings: runtime might deteriorate significantly.)

---

I did some timing with a sample file with 1_000_000 rows and 1_000 customers. Time for 10 executions (using `timeit`):

1. Sharim Iqbal's solution (accepted answer): 933 seconds
2. Pandas version in this answer: 16 seconds
3. Python-`groupby` version in this answer: 17 seconds
4. Slightly modified version of gimix solution: 16 seconds
5. Last version in this answer: 11 seconds

So, if you want to minimise the amount of code then use 2. Otherwise take your pick from 3. - 5. But don't use 1.: it's rather an example of how you shouldn't do it (and, tbh, the answer shouldn't be accepted).

PS: Don't shoot at the messenger ;)

Comment: thank you @timus, you tested them all and said which one was the best.
I will adapt it to my own file and try them all. thank you for your hard work.